# Google Cloud Compute Python API Isn't Accepting My Startup Script

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Here is my request body:

```
server = {
'name': name_gen.haikunate(),
'machineType': f"zones/{zone}/machineTypes/n1-standard-1",
'disks': [
    {
        'boot': True,
        'autoDelete': True,
        'initializeParams': {
            'sourceImage': 'projects/ubuntu-os-cloud/global/images/ubuntu-1604-xenial-v20191204'
        }
    }
],
'networkInterfaces': [
    {
        'network': '/global/networks/default',
        'accessConfigs': [
            {'type': 'ONE_TO_ONE_NAT', 'name': 'external nat'}
        ]
    }
],
'metadata': {
    'items': [
        {
            'keys': 'startup-script',
            'value': startup_script
        }
    ]
}
```

When using this request body with the compute object to create a vm, it is giving me this error:

```
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError:
<HttpError 400 when requesting https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/focal-maker-240918/zones/us-east4-c/instances?alt=json
returned "Invalid value for field 'resource.metadata': 
'{
   "item": [
   {
     "value": "#!/bin/bash\n\napt-get update\n\nsleep 15\n\nclear\n\napt-get install squ...'. Metadata invalid keys:">'
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can we focus in on the value of "startup_script" variable.  Where and how is it defined?  What exactly does it contain?  If you don't set metadata, does the command otherwise succeed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for setting metadata on a Compute Engine instance found [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMetadata) we see that the structure is:

```
"items": [
  {
    "key": string,
    "value": string
  }
],
```

if we compare that to your structure described in your post, we see you have coded `keys` instead of `key` as the field name.  This could easily be the issue.  To resolve the problem, change `keys` to `key`.